# New ABI for the GPIO Character device

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi-os

I was going through the presentation<sup>1</sup> about the new ABI of the GPIO Character device, presumably merged in v5.9 of the linux.

I installed a new version of raspberry os, (**uname**: *Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1414 SMP Fri Apr 30 13:20:47 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux*) but unfortunately found out there is still ABI v1 only inside /usr/include/linux/gpio.h.

Is there any information available when we can expect the new ABI to be part of the raspberry os?

---

<sup>1</sup>https://elinux.org/images/c/cb/Linux_GPIO-Evolution_and_Current_State_of_the_User_API.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange.  I am using version 2 of the /dev/gpiochip API on my recently updated Pis (mainly because API 2 has broken API 1).

Version 2 of the gpiochip API is present in all the Pis I have recently updated (32 and 64 bit).

For instance my Pi3B+

```
uname -a
Linux pi3bp 5.10.17-v7+ #1421 SMP Thu May 27 13:59:01 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

A fragment of `/usr/include/linux/gpio.h`

```
#define GPIO_V2_LINES_MAX 64

/*
 * The maximum number of configuration attributes associated with a line
 * request.
 */
#define GPIO_V2_LINE_NUM_ATTRS_MAX 10

/**
 * enum gpio_v2_line_flag - &struct gpio_v2_line_attribute.flags values
 * @GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_USED: line is not available for request
 * @GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_ACTIVE_LOW: line active state is physical low
 * @GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_INPUT: line is an input
 * @GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_OUTPUT: line is an output
 * @GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_EDGE_RISING: line detects rising (inactive to active)
 * edges
 * @GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_EDGE_FALLING: line detects falling (active to
 * inactive) edges
```

I suggest you update your Pi, perhaps with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Yeah, strangely, that helped. I even had corrupted package apt package file. Anyway solved now. Thanks!

Comment: on the unrelevant note, do you, by any chance, know where I could find the datasheet for the PLLs registers description?

Comment: What do you mean by PLLs registers?

Comment: I am looking for a register description of A2W_PLL*_CTRL, A2W_PLL*_ANA0, A2W_PLL*_FRAC and so on.. to determine a frequency of PLL*_per clock sources.

Comment: No idea.  Search shows https://elinux.org/The_Undocumented_Pi#Clocks I don't touch the PLLs and have never studied them.